# Python concat through a list of strings inside a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I have this df:

```
name | attach
John | ['0001','0002']
Peter | ['0003']
```

I need to transform each value in attach list to a link:
For example:

```
name | attach
John | ['http://www.test.com/0001/download', 'http://www.test.com/0002/download']
Peter | ['http://www.test.com/0003/download']
```

Where each value is the key in link to download.

I tried to use apply func but doesn't worked:

```
link_part1 = 'http://www.test.com/'
link_part2 = '/download'

df['attach'] = df['attach'].apply(lambda x: x if x is np.NaN else link_part1 + x + link_part2)
```

the following error is displayed:
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the error message: It tells you that you are trying to concatenate a list to a str, which only can be referring to the '+' operations you use in the lambda function.
You almost had it right, though, as you just need to consider the fact that the entries in 'attach' are *lists of strings* and not *strings* themselves:

```
df['attach'] = df['attach'].apply(lambda x: x if x is np.NaN else [link_part1+id+link_part2 for id in x])
```

should work.

Answer (score 2):

In your example above, the `attach` column contains lists, so when you attempt to add your two strings `link_part1` and `link_part2`, you get this TypeError, since you can't concatenate these types.

You'll want to do this sort of transformation to every element of the lists in `attach`. Also, make the code a little cleaner by defining a function, rather than using a lambda in this case. It's a little long for a lambda:

```
def make_link(attach):
    start = 'http://www.test.com/'
    end = '/download'
    return [f"{start}{x}{end}" for x in attach]

df['attach'] = df['attach'].apply(make_link)
```